# extjs4 row styling

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have conditional styling on grid rows, styling works initially but it does not respond to data change. Lets say if you edit a column to be a minus value lets say then I want its style change back to red.

I tried

```
grid.doLayout();
grid.doComponentLayout();
grid.update();
grid.updateLayout()
```

so how I can enforce grid to update the css on the row (how do I trigger getRowClass, or is there any other way of doing this).

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do will only be possible if you <s>run `reconfigure` with the same columnmodel on the grid.</s> override the `getRowClass` property of the view cause the grid.Panel itself has none.

```
gridReference.getView().getRowClass = function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){ 
     // your code 
}
```

See the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/K68Dd/1/)** example for this

***Alternatively you may use the renderer***

Use the renderer but this time you change the meta data of the cell by adding a class. This can be done by modifing the second param of the renderer which is a meta-object like so:

```
var classRenderer = function(v,m) { 
    if (v=='Lisa') { 
        m.tdCls = 'demo' 
    } 
    return v; 
}
```

here'S a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/17/)** in addition

Comment: @hazimdikenli I corrected my answer. It is possible to change the property of a instance. Se my Edit for details along with a example

Answer (score 0):

You can use the renderer config for the column...

```
 function change(val) {
    if (val > 0) {
        return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span>';
    } else if (val < 0) {
        return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
    }
    return val;
}

   function pctChange(val) {
    if (val > 0) {
        return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '%</span>';
    } else if (val < 0) {
        return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '%</span>';
    }
    return val;
}

   // create the Grid
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    stateful: true,
    collapsible: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    stateId: 'stateGrid',
    columns: [
        {
            text     : 'Company',
            flex     : 1,
            sortable : false,
            dataIndex: 'company'
        },
        {
            text     : 'Price',
            width    : 75,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : 'usMoney',
            dataIndex: 'price'
        },
        {
            text     : 'Change',
            width    : 75,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : change,
            dataIndex: 'change'
        },
        {
            text     : '% Change',
            width    : 75,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : pctChange,
            dataIndex: 'pctChange'
        },
        {
            text     : 'Last Updated',
            width    : 85,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
            dataIndex: 'lastChange'
        }
          ],
 height: 350,
    width: 600,
    title: 'Array Grid',
    renderTo: 'grid-example',
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true,
        enableTextSelection: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, this looks like an alternative way of coloring the cells, but I'd be happy if I could move on with the current 'getRowClass' way of coloring the rows.